# How to make a query to pivot/aggregate like this?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

How would I query this data set:

```
SessionId | GameMode | Score
----------|----------|-------
1         | 1        | 100
1         | 1        | 90
1         | 2        | 20
1         | 2        | 15
1         | 3        | 5
1         | 3        | 5
2         | 1        | 90
2         | 1        | 80
2         | 2        | 15
2         | 2        | 15
2         | 3        | 2
2         | 3        | 4
```

to turn it into:

```
SessionId | GameMode1AvgScore  | GameMode2AvgScore | GameMode3AvgScore
----------|--------------------|-------------------|-------------------
1         | 95                 | 17.5              | 5
2         | 85                 | 15                | 3
```

To clarify, I'm not asking how to group or aggregate rows, the core of my question is rather how do I pivot the `GameMode` rows into a column?

Comment: Instead, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry I have considered this but unfortunately, _Grafana_, the consumer cannot process the stored procedure output any futher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MySQL, to return the specified resultset, we would need a query (`SELECT` statement) that returns four columns.

```
 SELECT expr1    AS SessionId
      , expr2    AS GameMode1AvgScore
      , expr3    AS GameMode2AvgScore
      , expr4    AS GameMode3AvgScore
 FROM ... 
GROUP BY SessionId
```

---

MySQL does not yet provide "PIVOT" (ala SQL Server and PostgreSQL) or "MODEL" (ala Oracle) features.

So in terms of achieving this result from a SQL SELECT statement, we are left with old-school conditional aggregation,

```
 AVG(CASE WHEN t.GameMode = 1 THEN t.Score ELSE NULL END) AS GameMode1AvgScore
```

which seems to fall into the "how to group or aggregate rows" bucket you are not asking about. We can use a second SQL statement to help us build the SQL statement we need to run, but seems like that would still fall into the "how to group or aggregate rows".  In fact, any SQL statement that produces the specified result is going to need to aggregate rows.

So with that tool excluded from our MySQL toolbelts, that leaves us with one answer:  it is not possible to "pivot" GamerMode values into columns.

---

A statement to return the specified result might be like this:

```
 SELECT t.sessionid                                              AS SessionId
      , AVG(CASE WHEN t.GameMode = 1 THEN t.Score ELSE NULL END) AS GameMode1AvgScore
      , AVG(CASE WHEN t.GameMode = 2 THEN t.Score ELSE NULL END) AS GameMode2AvgScore
      , AVG(CASE WHEN t.GameMode = 3 THEN t.Score ELSE NULL END) AS GameMode3AvgScore
    --                             ^                                        ^
 FROM t
GROUP BY t.sessionid
ORDER BY t.sessionid
```

Note how expressions to return the average scores are the same pattern, we're just  substutiting in a value of `GameMode`.

To help us write the query, we could run an initial query to get a distinct list of `GameMode` values, either from the same table

```
SELECT q.GameMode FROM t q GROUP BY q.GameMode ORDER BY q.GameMode
```

or we could query a "dimension" table of GameMode if that exists.

We cycle through the resultset (`GameMode` values) and generate the expression required to return the average score for each `GameMode`. And we can use that to construct the SQL statement.

Comment: I'm interested in your solution involving a second SQL statement, could you expand on that?

Comment: To clarify, I didn't want to forbid the use of any tools, my intention was to avoid explanations of how to calculate averages or group rows in general in any answers for the benefit of any answerers.